# want to find specific string from given text using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want specific string from below text using regex.

```
str = 'Supervision68 - Outdoor Supervision In Compliance922 KAR 2:100 - 
Section 10(15) Each child'
```

Specific string : '68 - Outdoor Supervision In Compliance'

I have tried an get below result:

```
re.findall('\d+(.*?)922', str)
```

result: ' - Outdoor Supervision In Compliance'

Comment: Remove the capturing group, and lookahead for `922` instead of matching it (or capture the whole thing you want to match, like below)

Comment: Move the starting `(` before `\d+` (and the plus is redundant here): `'(\d.*?)922'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
import re
str = 'Supervision68 - Outdoor Supervision In Compliance922 KAR 2:100 - Section 10(15) Each child'
print(re.findall('(\d.*?)922', str))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['68 - Outdoor Supervision In Compliance']
```